# Why isn't the screenshot working?

Tags: gnome-screenshot

When taking a screenshot, there is a gray image displayed.

Before upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 the screenshot was working properly, however, after the upgrading process the screenshot wont work no more. I tried to verify which package was the problem from: gnome-screenshot, I unistalled it and installed back on my laptop, but it wont work anyways.

Comment: You could maybe try `shutter` via `sudo apt-get install shutter`. It's a pretty decent screenshot tool, and it might not be worth spending time trying to fix gnome-screenshot.

Comment: screenshot,gimp,shutter all of them don't work and just gives me a blank screen. This bug is new to 13.04 and Would really like it if it got fixed

Comment: Update: It was automaticaly fixed on a software update. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 ! I installed shutter, flameshot and gnome-screenshot. None work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem, even with Shutter, the only way I found to be able to fix it is to reset Unity.

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/


unity --reset-icons
```

Easy to do, but not suitable for everyone I guess.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04

Comment: Word to the wise: This remove all your side bar icons. Though I would try it out of desperation. It didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

you can also try the handy ...

```
gnome-screenshot --interactive
```

Comment: to select part of the screen directly use `gnome-screenshot --interactive -c -a -e shadow`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that gnome-screenshot was never installed..

So I ran

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot
```

and obviously it solved my problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu. This is a relevant point, but should be added as a comment *(even though you do not have enough reputation yet)*. Please note that the OP *(Original Poster)* has said that they answered the question 2 days ago :-)